# Postgresql - How to identify latest record of a combination of 2 columns (Example inside)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, inner-join

In PostgreSQL, if i have this kind of record :

```
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|  corona_country  |   corona_patient    | corona_suspected |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     Mexico       |        Teddy        |    2020-03-01    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     Indonesia    |        Andy         |    2020-03-01    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     Indonesia    |        Andy         |    2020-03-05    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     China        |        Sarah        |    2020-03-04    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     UK           |        Michael      |    2020-03-05    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     Italy        |        Michael      |    2020-03-15    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     Italy        |        Michael      |    2020-03-15    |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to add extra column (by a Select query) that identifies if a combination of corona_country and corona_patient is having the latest date (of corona_suspected column) among its own records. So it'll look like this :

```
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|  corona_country  |   corona_patient    | corona_suspected |  LATEST?  |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     Mexico       |        Teddy        |    2020-03-01    |     Y     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     Indonesia    |        Andy         |    2020-03-01    |     N     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     Indonesia    |        Andy         |    2020-03-05    |     Y     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     China        |        Sarah        |    2020-03-04    |     Y     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     UK           |        Michael      |    2020-03-05    |     Y     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     Italy        |        Michael      |    2020-03-13    |     N     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     Italy        |        Michael      |    2020-03-15    |     Y     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|     Italy        |        Michael      |    2020-03-15    |     Y     |
|------------------|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
```

How can i achieve this by sql query? Is there any method that joins another table that records latest dates of each combination of corona_country and corona_patient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using `MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY..)` analytic function

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 
       WHEN( MAX( corona_suspected ) OVER 
                ( PARTITION BY corona_country, corona_patient ) = corona_suspected )
       THEN 
         'Y'
       ELSE
         'N'
       END AS latest
  FROM t
```

OR alternatively

Use `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function

```
   CASE 
   WHEN(DENSE_RANK() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY corona_country, corona_patient ORDER BY corona_suspected DESC )=1)
   THEN 
     'Y'
   ELSE
     'N'
   END AS latest
```

in order to return the result with **ties**(*more than one latest values for `corona_suspected` columns for each groups*)

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0b582cc55e56122b512e37f3ccadc49f)</kbd>

Comment: That's cool ! I think i'll pick your answer. By the way, what column should i index to speed up the query? :)

Comment: that's nice @DyaksaHanindito . Performance of the index would depend on your where clause which you'll use. Have a look at the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (rank() over (partition by corona_country, corona_patient order by corono_suspected desc) = 1
       ) as is_latest
from t;
```

Note that this creates a boolean value.  If you want a string, use `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when rank() over (partition by corona_country, corona_patient order by corono_suspected desc) = 1
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as is_latest
from t;
```

Comment: Sorry, i've changed my question a little :(

Comment: @DyaksaHanindito . . . You just want `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.